# Convert a BC date to an AD

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have dates, which are prior to year 0. I need to convert them to an AD date and add 1 year more. For example I have `BC 16.2.2011` and want `AD 16.2.2012`.

We have a 3rd side Java application, in which sometimes an error occurs; it saves the date incorrectly. In example above it should save `16.2.2012` but instead, in the DB, is `-16.2.2011` (it is one "year smaller" because Oracle has no year zero - this is important).

Converting these dates is easy, but the problem is that when a saved date should be `29.2.2012` because there is no `-29.2.2011`. Instead of this date it saves `-1.3.2011`, which I can't convert easily.

Is there any way to convert the date correctly? Like get seconds from start year right from dump data in the database?

Comment: Actually IIRC there was no year zero, so Oracle is correct here. Go figure, humans like to count from 1. Not that it helps your question of course.

Comment: Why do you tagged this with PL/SQL? Do you need a stored procedure?

Comment: I didn't undestood the `problem is when saved date should be like 29.2.2012 because there is no -29.2.2011, so instead of this date it saves -1.3.2011. ` part. You don't want to add one day in this case?

Comment: How is the invalid date stored - can you add a `dump` of the values, particularly the problematic ones? From the description it looks like the application is corrupting the data during the insert, which might be a JDBC bug - even if you can't fix the application, if a later JDBC driver still works it might eliminate the issue, perhaps?

Comment: I taged it plsql beacuse I want to write trigger which will correct date to right one :) I'm unable to do any modification in java app including changing JDBC driver. I have only possibility to do modifications in DB.

Comment: Florin Ghita: problem is with leap years :)

Comment: @bakua - OK, but you need to be able to identify 'bad' dates - which may be simple in most cases (e.g. just anything BC) - but if you see `-1.3.2011`, how will you decide if it should be `29.2.2012` or `1.3.2012`? *If* they are corrupt you may be able to distinguish, but it isn't clear, and it seems a bit unlikely that they would be corrupted so neatly. Can you `select dump(<date_field>, 16` from your table for some of these dates and add the results to the question?

Comment: Yes I will post here dump date when I'll be in work. And you are right, all bc dates are wrong. Also you wrote "but if you see -1.3.2011" - yes, that only representation of dump data. Date is stored in long where some bytes mean something... and by those values date interpretation is showed. Problem is that this representation is calculated relatively to year 1, not year 0 - that's why there is the difference in years I was tanking about.

Comment: so there comes the dump: date = bc 31.05.2014 00:00:00; dump = Typ=12 Len=7: 80,86,5,31,1,1,1

Answer (score 0):

Tell us if it is something wrong with:

```
select to_date(to_char(your_bc_date_here,'dd.mm.YYYY'), 'dd.mm.YYYY') + 1 from dual;
```

This is a *wrong* cast because it does not considers year may be negative(*correct* would be `syyyy`)

I've tested with: `your_bc_date = to_date('BC 28.2.2011', 'BC dd.mm.yyyy')`